# Update password across all SSRS reports within a folder in Reporting services 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssrs, ssrs-2016

I am going through a manual intervention of manually updating the password in data source section for all the reports in SSRS2016.

This is very tedious as i need to update this across 40+reports manually by going to manage-> data source and updating the password everytime the AD account has been expired or  reset , one used in SSRS reorts.

How can i make this less tedious may be via some powershell to update the password across all reports within same Data source?

Comment: You can use the build in SOAP webservices: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-web-service/report-server-web-service?view=sql-server-2017  though it may take you longer to write the code than just update the password :)

Comment: @SeanGallardy: I have to do above across 2 diff environments and for 40+reports and moreover password keeps and need to change every 2 months. so this would be more tedious doing it again and again.  I see some PS https://powershell.org/forums/topic/update-datasource-and-subscription-password-for-ssrs/ but they are not working on ssrs2016 somehow

Comment: Can you change the reports to use a Shared Data Source instead? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/create-modify-and-delete-shared-data-sources-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017